# Comparing 2 Pandas dataframes row by row and performing a calculation on each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I have created 2 Pandas dataframes and I need to compare rows in DF1 to rows in DF2, by way of a 2-column distance function.

Basically I need every row in DF2 to be compared to row 1 in DF 1; every row in DF2 to be compared to row 2 in DF1, etc provided they have the **same Participant number** and **same Trial number**. If the resulting distance value is less than a specific threshold, I need to document what row that was from DF2 in a new column.

I'm very new to Pandas, so I'm not quite sure where to start with this, but I have detailed the step-by-step logic of my problem below.

Here are my 2 dataframes (samples - the actual dataframes will be extremely large; 10,000+ rows each):

DF1:

| IP_INDEX | IP_LABEL | PARTICIPANT | TRIAL | CURRENT_FIX_INDEX | PRE_FIX_X | PRE_FIX_Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | a | 1 | 1 | 550 | 150 |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | a | 1 | 2 | 600 | 300 |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | a | 2 | 1 | 250 | 600 |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | b | 1 | 1 | 400 | 400 |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | b | 2 | 1 | 600 | 400 |

DF2:

| IP_INDEX | IP_LABEL | PARTICIPANT | TRIAL | CURRENT_FIX_INDEX | POST_FIX_X | POST_FIX_Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2nd 3 Seconds | a | 1 | 1 | 500 | 200 |
| 2 | 2nd 3 Seconds | a | 1 | 2 | 650 | 350 |
| 2 | 2nd 3 Seconds | a | 2 | 1 | 300 | 650 |
| 2 | 2nd 3 Seconds | b | 1 | 1 | 250 | 700 |
| 2 | 2nd 3 Seconds | b | 1 | 2 | 450 | 150 |
| 2 | 2nd 3 Seconds | b | 2 | 1 | 550 | 350 |
| 2 | 2nd 3 Seconds | b | 2 | 2 | 350 | 550 |

Here is what I need (example for any given row):

1. Create a new column in DF1 called 'REFIX'. This will be blank for now, but cells will get filled in later based on the formula below.
2. If DF2 'PARTICIPANT' == DF1 'PARTICIPANT *and* DF2 'TRIAL' == DF1 'TRIAL',

   1. Then calculate math.dist(p, q) where p and q are defined by the ***_FIX_X and ***_FIX_Y values from DF1 and DF2 (the *** stands for PRE or POST based on whether it's DF1 or DF2).
   2. Else (*i.e. If DF2 'PARTICIPANT' != DF1 'PARTICIPANT' *or* DF2 'TRIAL' != DF1 'TRIAL')*, then move on to the next row in DF2
3. If result of math.dist(p, q) <= 150, then fill in 'REFIX' column in DF1 (for the row we're on in DF1) with the value of CURRENT_FIX_INDEX in DF2 (for the row that we're on in DF2)
4. Save DF1 as a new csv file

I'm not sure if I'm correct here, but this is what I have for determining the p and q values for the math.dist(p, q) function:

```
# Define p and q values for distance calculation
p = [(df1['PRE_FIX_X']), (df1['PRE_FIX_Y'])]
q = [(df2['POST_FIX_X']), (df2['POST_FIX_Y'])]
```

Based on the example dataframes given, a complete DF1 file would look like this:

| IP_INDEX | IP_LABEL | PARTICIPANT | TRIAL | CURRENT_FIX_INDEX | PRE_FIX_X | PRE_FIX_Y | REFIX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | a | 1 | 1 | 550 | 150 | 1 |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | a | 1 | 2 | 600 | 300 | 1,2 |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | a | 2 | 1 | 250 | 600 | 1 |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | b | 1 | 1 | 400 | 400 |  |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | b | 2 | 1 | 600 | 400 | 1 |

Comment: Hello, are you saying the distance calculation is to be operated ONLY by between rows that have identical PARTICPANT and TRIAL numbers? This is not so clear to me after parsing your text.
So you want to know who moved significantly in between 2 fragments of a trial.

Comment: Yes, the distance calculation only needs to be done when those 2 variables (Participant and Trial) match across dataframes. And yes, I guess that is a good way to put that!

Comment: Next, what happens with rows within one dataframe that share the same ip, participant, and trial? You didn't mention a pre-processing such as averaging Xs and Ys. You seem to indicate to treat them separately? Yeah, according to desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

****EDITED:** Now includes count of REFIXes per trial as requested in comments**

Your problem appears quite complex and was a smidge hard to follow but I think this may be what you want?

I don't think iterating through the two df's with nested if statements is the most efficient route but I can't think of a better option right now :)

Part 1: Loading in the data you provided: (You can obviously ignore this bit, but putting it in for easy reproducibility/testing:

```
import pandas as pd

# Define the data for DF1
data_df1 = {
    'IP_INDEX': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'IP_LABEL': ['1st 3 Seconds', '1st 3 Seconds', '1st 3 Seconds', '1st 3 Seconds', '1st 3 Seconds'],
    'PARTICIPANT': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
    'TRIAL': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    'CURRENT_FIX_INDEX': [1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
    'PRE_FIX_X': [550, 600, 250, 400, 600],
    'PRE_FIX_Y': [150, 300, 600, 400, 400]
}

# Create DF1
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_df1)

data_df2 = {
    'IP_INDEX': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'IP_LABEL': ['2nd 3 Seconds', '2nd 3 Seconds', '2nd 3 Seconds', '2nd 3 Seconds', '2nd 3 Seconds', '2nd 3 Seconds', '2nd 3 Seconds'],
    'PARTICIPANT': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'TRIAL': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'CURRENT_FIX_INDEX': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    'POST_FIX_X': [500, 650, 300, 250, 450, 550, 350],
    'POST_FIX_Y': [200, 350, 650, 700, 150, 350, 550]
}

# Create DF2
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_df2)
```

Part 2: Doing the calculations:

```
import math

#Create function to calculate distance between coordinates
def calculate_distance(df1_row,df2_row):
    p = (df1_row['PRE_FIX_X'], df1_row['PRE_FIX_Y'])
    q = (df2_row['POST_FIX_X'], df2_row['POST_FIX_Y'])
    return math.dist(p, q)

refix_values = [] #Create empty list to hold lists of matching FIX_INDEX values in df2

for index, df1_row in df1.iterrows(): #Iterate through each row in df1
    fix_index_list = [] #Create empty list to hold matching INDEX values for loop row
    df2_subset = df2.loc[(df2['PARTICIPANT'] == df1_row['PARTICIPANT']) & (df2['TRIAL'] == df1_row['TRIAL'])] #Subset out matching data in df2 so we're not looping through the entirety of df2
    for i, df2_row in df2_subset.iterrows(): #Iterate through df2 subset
        dist = calculate_distance(df1_row,df2_row) #Calculate dist for each row
        if dist <= 150:
            fix_index_list.append(df2_row['CURRENT_FIX_INDEX']) #Add dist to list if greater or equal to 150
    refix_values.append(','.join(map(str, fix_index_list))) #Add list of matching INDEX values to list of lists

df1['REFIX'] = refix_values #Convert list of lists to new column

def count_refix_items(row_refix_value):
    integers = [int(s) for s in row_refix_value.split(',') if s.isdigit()] #Split string by commas and count resultant elements
    return len(integers)

refix_per_trial = df1[df1['REFIX'].notna()].groupby(['TRIAL','PARTICIPANT'])['REFIX'].apply(lambda x: x.apply(count_refix_items).sum()).reset_index()
refix_per_trial = refix_per_trial.rename(columns={'REFIX': 'REFIXes/trial/participant'}) #Rename column

df1 = pd.merge(df1, refix_per_trial, on = ['TRIAL','PARTICIPANT'], how = 'outer')

#Write df to csv
df1.to_csv('REFIX_calc_output.tab', sep='\t', index=False) #Change name of file to whatever you want
```

The output I got using the input you provided:

| IP_INDEX | IP_LABEL | PARTICIPANT | TRIAL | CURRENT_FIX_INDEX | PRE_FIX_X | PRE_FIX_Y | REFIX | REFIXes/trial/participant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | a | 1 | 1 | 550 | 150 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | a | 1 | 2 | 600 | 300 | 1,2 | 3 |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | a | 2 | 1 | 250 | 600 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | b | 1 | 1 | 400 | 400 |  | 0 |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | b | 2 | 1 | 600 | 400 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to reproduce this and it seems to work perfectly! I just tested it on my actual data files with some hand checking and it also works! I sincerely appreciate your help, I have been struggling for way too long!!
If I wanted to count the number of items in the REFIX column per trial, where would I add that statement to get this number in a new column? The number can be in every row for a trial, that's fine (ie, Trial 1 above has 3 REFIXes (1 in row1, 2 in row2) so both row 1 and row 2 could say '3' in the new column).

Comment: Yay! Happy this worked for you :) If you wouldn't mind clicking on accepted answer, that would be awesome. As for the counting up of refixes per trial: That should be easy enough. Do you need it per participant again? Or just an overall count per trial? And is it ok if it's in a separate table or do you want it in df1?

Comment: Absolutely! And yes, per participant. In the same df (df1) would be preferable, however any way it's easiest works for me!

Comment: Updated for the REFIXes column to be grouped by TRIAL and PARTICIPANT, not just TRIAL (as I had it before).

Comment: Thank you! I've been playing around with this and I'm getting myself totally confused, but is there a way to differentiate between 0s in the COUNT_REFIX column when there are 0 matches according to the formula and when there is nothing to compare to? There are some rows in df1 that have no corresponding rows in df2 (matched by participant & trial), if that makes sense. I.E. participant a has no data for trial 2 in df2, but there is data for trial 1 in df1. Is there a way to make this an NaN (or something? to distinguish?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to figure it out! Thank you for putting up with me! :)

Comment: Sweet! :) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

1. `merge` both DataFrames
2. Calculate the distance
3. Assign `REFIX` when distance is less than 150
4. Format `REFIX` as string for aggregation
5. `groupby` and `agg` to get the required output

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, on=["PARTICIPANT","TRIAL"], suffixes=("","_y"))
merged["DIST"] = (merged["PRE_FIX_X"].sub(merged["POST_FIX_X"]).pow(2).add(merged["PRE_FIX_Y"].sub(merged["POST_FIX_Y"]).pow(2))).pow(0.5)
merged["REFIX"] = merged["CURRENT_FIX_INDEX_y"].where(merged["DIST"].lt(150))
merged["REFIX"] = merged["REFIX"].fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str).replace({"0":""})

output = merged.groupby(list(df1.columns), as_index=False)["REFIX"].agg(",".join)
output["REFIX"] = output["REFIX"].str.rstrip(",")

>>> output
   IP_INDEX       IP_LABEL PARTICIPANT  TRIAL  CURRENT_FIX_INDEX  PRE_FIX_X  \
0         1  1st 3 Seconds           a      1                  1        550   
1         1  1st 3 Seconds           a      1                  2        600   
2         1  1st 3 Seconds           a      2                  1        250   
3         1  1st 3 Seconds           b      1                  1        400   
4         1  1st 3 Seconds           b      2                  1        600   

   PRE_FIX_Y REFIX  
0        150     1  
1        300   1,2  
2        600     1  
3        400        
4        400     1
```